# Math: More control on Integer Partition Functions and Algorithm

Tags: python, math, integer, partition

Integer partitions is a very interesting topic. Creating all the partitions of a given integer is almost simple, such as the following code:

```
def aP(n):
    """Generate partitions of n as ordered lists in ascending
    lexicographical order.

    This highly efficient routine is based on the delightful
    work of Kelleher and O'Sullivan."""

    a = [1]*n
    y = -1
    v = n
    while v > 0:
        v -= 1
        x = a[v] + 1
        while y >= 2 * x:
            a[v] = x
            y -= x
            v += 1
        w = v + 1
        while x <= y:
            a[v] = x
            a[w] = y
            yield a[:w + 1]
            x += 1
            y -= 1
        a[v] = x + y
        y = a[v] - 1
        yield a[:w]
```

Searching for a way to gain much more control over the function, for example in order to generate only the partitions of N size, this solution appears better:

```
def sum_to_n(n, size, limit=None):
    """Produce all lists of `size` positive integers in decreasing order
    that add up to `n`."""
    if size == 1:
        yield [n]
        return
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    start = (n + size - 1) // size
    stop = min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1
    for i in range(start, stop):           
        for tail in sum_to_n(n - i, size - 1, i):
            yield [i] + tail
```

But both of them do generates ALL the possible partitions of the given number, the first with every size, the second of the given size. What if I want only one specific partition of a given number ?
The following code generates the next partition of a given partition:

```
def next_partition(p):
  if max(p) == 1:
    return [sum(p)]
  p.sort()
  p.reverse()
  q = [ p[n] for n in range(len(p)) if p[n] > 1 ]
  q[-1] -= 1
  if (p.count(1)+1) % q[-1] == 0: 
    return q + [q[-1]]*((p.count(1)+1) // q[-1])
  else:
    return q + [q[-1]]*((p.count(1)+1) // q[-1]) + [(p.count(1)+1) % q[-1]]
```

But still there is a problem, you have to know what is the partition before the partition requested.

Suppose now to need a given partition of an integer N and you only know the number of the partition; example:

The partitions of 4 are:

```
n.1 4
n.2 3+1
n.3 2+2
n.4 2+1+1
n.5 1+1+1+1
```

How to create the partition number 2 (3+1) giving only the integer (4) and the sequence number (2) ? All of this without the creation of all the partitions ?
I have read somewhere that is possible with a mathematic formula but I do not know how.